# Set "Audience Targeting" via Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I've created a power automate flow that automatically creates a page from an item when the item is created.  Everything works fine except the ability to add audience targeting.   I've enabled audience targeting  in the library settings under "Audience targeting settings".  I then created a 'template' and am calling 'get file metadata' from the flow, then 'update file properties' and I dont see audience as option.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you don’t have an audience claims like this:

[image]

If so, will other users have the same issue when using the "Update file properties" operation?

I cannot reproduce your issue, please create a new flow in another library with audiences enabled to check if the issue persists.

Comment: Thank you for replying!  I did see that one, but I guess I didnt think that was it because I cant seem to add a variable to the value.    I'm wanting to set the audience based on a condition above.  To which i'm saving the JSON code for the groups and wanting to put it in there.